# How do I bypass bot recognition tools for selenium-webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

I am trying to make a copycat bot for SoundCloud using python-selenium. 
It will follow these steps:

1. Log you in
2. Search inputted Profile
3. Make lists of inputted Profiles like tracks and who it's following.
4. Then it will like those tracks and follow those people.

This is not going to be a spam bot, it will be used for data collection of the profiles I am interested in.

I can do all of this myself I just recently started running into a denial of login that says "Our robots think you are a robot.
Try reloading the page. If you continue to have this problem, please visit our Help center."
How do I bypass this?

Here is my code(shortened) so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class SoundCloudBot:

    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password =  password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()

    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://soundcloud.com/signin?redirect_url=/stream')
        time.sleep(3)
        email = bot.find_element_by_id('formControl_72')
        email.click()
        email.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        email.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(3)
        creds = bot.find_element_by_id('formControl_84')
        creds.send_keys(self.password)
        creds.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

sync = SoundCloudBot('yourEmail', 'yourPassword')

sync.login()
```

Comment: You use their API: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide.

Comment: if your bot could bypass them, they wouldn't be very useful bot detection tools, would they?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, and works most of the time for me, it's to make your time.sleep random. Bots are pace keeping and humans are more erratics.

You need to import random library

```
import random
```

Then you change your time.sleep for something like this:

```
time.sleep(random.randint(3,15))
```

Answer (score 0):

As powerPixie mentioned, adding sleeps and waits strategically to mirror human behavior is a good place to start.  Try to find that happy medium between going fast enough to triggering bot detection and going so slow that your automation is only marginally faster than doing it manually.

I also know that some sites disable captcha or other "I am not a robot" tests if you are signed into gmail/google on another tab (not sure if this is the case with Soundcloud).

Since Soundcloud has an error message like this prepared, chances are they don't want people automating processes on their site so they may have additional hurdles in place beyond what you've already discovered.  If they don't want bots on their site, its better to respect their request instead of getting an IP ban from the site.